# Branch.io not working in native mail app on iphone

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, branch.io

For some reason my branch links will work on my iphone in the gmail app but it won't work on the native mail app. I set up universal links, but might have forgot or did something wrong.

I have my app installed, but the link sends me to the web. On the gmail app it will send me to the app.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Opened a ticket with branch and received this:

> It seems like with Apple's recent minor update to 9.3.1, they
>   inadvertently broke Universal Links for a handful of use cases,
>   including for our domain (bnc.lt), as you've pointed out.
>
> We're super sorry for this inconvenience, so we'll be thinking through
>   work arounds (if possible) with respect to using our standard domain.
>   A workaround would be to use your own custom subdomain, in case you
>   need to be unblocked ASAP:
>   https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/advanced/ios/#using-a-custom-domain-or-subdomain